# How to get percentage by partitioning the data

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have attached my sample data here. I'm showing how my data actually looks (left side) and then how I have it currently on my view (right side). Count column is an aggregate measure which shows the distinct count of key values for group field.

I want to achieve results of percentage column such that:

- If rank =1 then count number of rows with rank !=1 and divide that by total rows i.e 10.
- If rank=2 then count number of rows with rank!=1 or rank!=2 and divide that by total rows i.e 10.
- If rank=3 then count number of rows with rank!=1 or rank!=2 or rank!=3 and divide that by total rows i.e 10. and so on.

Is this possible and if so please guide!

[Sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9f6l.jpg)

I tried to use windows function to partition my data, but since count is an aggregated measure to I couldn't use it in the partition window.